# Mouse events for canvas draw objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I want to create canvas-based site menu using [this](https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender) plugin, to create 'multiply' effect. However this, and also [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html), are working on ctx objects in the same canvas. (in context-blender it uses an off-screen canvas and uses its draw info, globalcompoperation blends the same ctx).
I want to create mouse events (hover and click) for each ctx object, so each ctx will lead to a different url.

Here is my test:

```
      function draw(){
      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvasOff1').getContext('2d');
      var ctx2 = document.getElementById('canvasReal').getContext('2d');
      var ctx3 = document.getElementById('canvasOff3').getContext('2d');

      // draw circles - each circle should link to different url and has its own focus
      ctx.fillStyle = "#c7302a";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(50,75,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx2.fillStyle = "#395797";
      ctx2.beginPath();
      ctx2.arc(100,75,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx2.fill();

  ctx3.fillStyle = "#454";
      ctx3.beginPath();
      ctx3.arc(150,75,35,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx3.fill();

    var over = canvasOff1.getContext('2d'); 
    var under = canvasReal.getContext('2d');
    over.blendOnto(under,'multiply');

    var over2 = canvasOff3.getContext('2d'); 
    var under2 = canvasReal.getContext('2d');
    over2.blendOnto(under2,'multiply',{destX:0,destY:0});
    }
```

Would be nice to know though how Can I implement jQuery here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add event listeners to a context, only to the canvas:

```
document.getElementById('canvasOff1').addEventLsitener(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test1.com'); }
);
document.getElementById('canvasReal').addEventLsitener(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test2.com'); }
);
document.getElementById('canvasOff3').addEventLsitener(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test3.com'); }
);

function goToUrl(url){
    window.location = url;
}
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$('#canvasOff1').on(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test1.com'); }
);
$('#canvasReal').on(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test2.com'); }
);
$('#canvasOff3').on(
    'click',
    function(){ goToUrl('http://www.test3.com'); }
);

function goToUrl(url){
    window.location = url;
}
```

(I prefer using a separate function for `window.location = X`, but of course, you couls also use it in the `onclick` function, like this:

```
function(){ window.location = 'http://www.test1.com'; }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replay.
This is however doesnt answer my question since both CanvasOff are off screen canvases. the only visible canvas is canvasReal - which takes information from the off-screen canvas and do the multipy manipulation. Maybe a solution with mouse location can do the job?

Comment: How can one click a canvas if it isn't on the screen? I mean, you can't see the element, so you can't click it, so you can't visit the page they're linking to.

Comment: That's was reason of my question - if I can create mouse event for a context object inside the canvas, and not for the canvas as a whole. The ctxs in the off screen canvas are shown on the real canvas.

Comment: Ah, then you'll have to determine the coordinates of the mouse click, and set the `window.location` depending on where the user clicked.

Comment: Thank you! any reference for using `window.location`?

Comment: Yup, have a look at [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)